# Query runs slower when SELECT clause is used

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have a query in SQL Server with 6 JOINs and 1 LEFT JOIN to tables and views. It returns 16k records in about 1 second if the select clause is "SELECT *"

As soon as I specify even one column to display (SELECT ItemID, for example) the query slows down to about 70 seconds.

Query #1 (2s) - SELECT *:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT LinkedToSet, LinkedToCopy, ',' + STRING_AGG(LocationID,',') + ',' Locs, count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY LinkedToSet) Copies
      FROM Inventory.Locations WHERE LinkedToSet is not null AND (State & 4096)>0 GROUP BY LinkedToSet, LinkedToCopy) l
    JOIN Bricklink_Set_Query bsq on l.LinkedToSet=bsq.Number
    JOIN Bricklink.Set_Parts_Query bsp on l.LinkedToSet=bsp.SetNum AND bsp.Extra=0
    JOIN Bricklink.Item_List i on bsp.ItemType=i.ItemType AND bsp.ItemID=i.Number
    JOIN Bricklink.Category_List cat on i.Category_ID=cat.CatID
    JOIN Bricklink.Color_List col on bsp.ColorID=col.ColorID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT LocationID, ItemType, ItemNum, ColorID, sum(QtyFound) as InvPcs 
                FROM Inventory.Item_History 
                GROUP BY LocationID, ItemType, ItemNum, ColorID) as h ON l.Locs like concat('%,',h.locationID,',%') AND h.ItemType=bsp.ItemType AND h.ItemNum=bsp.ItemID AND h.ColorID=bsp.ColorID
```

Actual Execution Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJD7Qemf_

Query #2 (81s) - SELECT a single column

```
SELECT bsp.ItemID
FROM (SELECT LinkedToSet, LinkedToCopy, ',' + STRING_AGG(LocationID,',') + ',' Locs, count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY LinkedToSet) Copies
      FROM Inventory.Locations WHERE LinkedToSet is not null AND (State & 4096)>0 GROUP BY LinkedToSet, LinkedToCopy) l
    JOIN Bricklink_Set_Query bsq on l.LinkedToSet=bsq.Number
    JOIN Bricklink.Set_Parts_Query bsp on l.LinkedToSet=bsp.SetNum AND bsp.Extra=0
    JOIN Bricklink.Item_List i on bsp.ItemType=i.ItemType AND bsp.ItemID=i.Number
    JOIN Bricklink.Category_List cat on i.Category_ID=cat.CatID
    JOIN Bricklink.Color_List col on bsp.ColorID=col.ColorID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT LocationID, ItemType, ItemNum, ColorID, sum(QtyFound) as InvPcs 
                FROM Inventory.Item_History 
                GROUP BY LocationID, ItemType, ItemNum, ColorID) as h ON l.Locs like concat('%,',h.locationID,',%') AND h.ItemType=bsp.ItemType AND h.ItemNum=bsp.ItemID AND h.ColorID=bsp.ColorID
```

Actual execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJTr4x7Gu

The execution plans look totally different from each other and I'm not sure why.  I've also tried wrapping the SELECT * and querying that, but some of these tables/views have the exact same field names, especially on the joins, so SQL Server throws an error:

> This column 'foo' was specified multiple times.

How do I achieve the performance of SELECT * but limit which columns I display?

P.S. 2 Notes - 1) My desired select statement is obviously more complex than this and 2) Even using the full select statement, if I add a WHERE clause and restrict the query there, it runs in <1 second. If that plan would be useful I can post it as well.

Comment: Considering a lot of your tables don't seem to have indexes, even clustered indexes, I think you should start there. A complex query like this, with poor access patterns, is going to confuse the compiler, so you just happened to get lucky on the `select *` query. Looking at it in SentryOne: you got a bunch of Sort spills, caused by wildly off cardinality estimates. Perhaps some choice filtered indexes may help here. You may find https://brentozar.com/ and https://use-the-index-luke.com/ useful

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look at that